# Is $\left\lVert x \right\rVert*x$ a function of class $C^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

I just liked to know if that function ($\left\lVert x \right\rVert*x$) is of class $C^{\infty}$ in $x=0$. I think it is'nt, and I proved that, but my teacher said me to prove that this function is of this class. 
Please tell me what you think about.

Comment: $f(x)=x|x|$ is $C^1$ but is not twice differentiable (just working in $\Bbb R$). It would appear you were correct.